# Replace the specific text between curley braces with java regx

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I need to replace the {0} with "D1" , {1} with "X0" , {2} with "DP12001" and so on...
I tried to write with regex and it was like this.

```
    String header = "{0}^{1}^{2}^{3}^{4}^{5}^{6}^{7}^{8}^{9}^{10}";
    String _header = "";
    String rl = "D1,X0,DP12001,1,2,10021521012,1,141128135639,1,12,0";
    logger.debug("rl-->{}", rl);
    String[] parts = rl.split(",");
    int partCount = 0;
    for (String part : parts) {
        _header = header.replaceAll("\\{." + partCount + "\\}", part);
        partCount++;
    }
```

I need the final output like this.
"D1^X0^DP12001^1^2^10021521012^1^141128135639^1^12^0"

but my code is not work as expected.

Comment: Please show the result/error/exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) here:

```
String header = "{0}^{1}^{2}^{3}^{4}^{5}^{6}^{7}^{8}^{9}^{10}";
String rl = "D1,X0,DP12001,1,2,10021521012,1,141128135639,1,12,0";
String[] parts = rl.split(",");
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(header, parts));
```

([live demo](http://ideone.com/1olOCW))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to keep in mind that [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) returns the resulting string.

Since you are doing 
`_header = header.replaceAll("\\{." + partCount + "\\}", part);`, the old `header` is used again and again on each loop.

Secondly, I think you could use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) in this case like this:

```
String header = "{0}^{1}^{2}^{3}^{4}^{5}^{6}^{7}^{8}^{9}^{10}";
String _header = header;
String rl = "D1,X0,DP12001,1,2,10021521012,1,141128135639,1,12,0";
String[] parts = rl.split(",");
int partCount = 0;
for (String part : parts) {
  _header = _header.replace("{" + partCount + "}", part);
  partCount++;
}
System.out.println(_header);
```